# For a browser-based turn-based board game, how to reload the page with the changes to the game?

Tags: javascript, html, css, database

I'm new to Javascript and as an exercise am doing a browser version of a board game.

Since I'm so new to the HTML world, I'd love to know a bit more how asynchronous games on websites like Boiteajeux.net work.

I can go through the steps in my game (I've programmed a lot of the logic), but I'm unsure how to "save" that information such that when the game loads again, the information of the changes have reloaded.

I don't know much about databases and how to store it, so maybe that's the hole in my knowledge.

I'd love to be able to, with each "move" in my game, have it be a permanent change to the webpage such that if I hit refresh, it doesn't return to the pre-game state.

How does this work?

Comment: You have options, but a lot of research in front of you. Databases make a lot of sense for this purpose. But in a pinch you can write some sort of JSON to determine move positions and lost from that. Or if things only need to persist locally; localstorage or cookies

Comment: You have found client side code's greatest weakness. Information only wants to live on a client's machine and only for as long as that session (browser window) is running.

Comment: @Doug that is not really accurate. Storage like localStorage and indexedDb persist on hard drive until cleared by user (or an app)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want local persistent state between refreshes, you could look into using localStorage. LocalStorage is a read-only property of the Document's storage object. Unlike SessionStorage, the data stored does not expire.

You can set key items in local storage like so:

`localStorage.setItem('myKey', 'some data');`

You can read the stored item like this:

`var myItem = localStorage.getItem('myKey');`

There are also `.remove('myKey')` and `.clear()` methods for deleteing items and clearing the storage object.

Assuming your game state is stored in some state object, you could store the stringified object when the state updates.

Something like:

`localStorage.setItem('gameState', JSON.stringify(currentState));`

And access the state on browser load like this:

`var currentState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('gameState'));`

This will be a lot easier than setting up a database, but if you want access to your game's state from another browser you will likely need to use a database.

Comment: Thanks. In an ideal world I would publish this game online in which case it would certainly need to be accessed by all asynchronous players on various browsers.

Comment: Of course, as it is a turn-based game (my bad). I would suggest perhaps a tutorial on a non-relational database like mongodb, as they tend to be easier to learn than relational databases like mySql.

Comment: Additionally, you will need to set up a backend to handle your database. The basic flow is this: your frontend will request data from the backend on load. Your backend will receive the request and grab the data from the database, then pass it back to your frontend. When the player has made their move, you will send another request to the backend with the player move data and update the database. I would suggest using node.js with express as a backend as then you can develop it in javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the details, @Rowan! I appreciate the time and tips.